# What is the symfony2 class type I should use for helper components

Tags: symfony

I have some logic that I want to be able to call from a controller, but I don't want it to reside within the controller. I want to provide a helper class that the controller calls into. I also want that helper class to be able to conveniently access the service container. What's the prescribed symfony way for doing that?

Comment: Your helper should be a service accessible via the service container.  Read and understand this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html before going too far.  Also, do your absolute best to avoid injecting the complete container into the helper.  You really want to just inject whatever the helper needs to it's job.

Comment: Thanks! If you post that as an answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your helper should be a service accessible via the service container.

Read and understand this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html before going too far.

Also, do your absolute best to avoid injecting the complete container into the helper. You really want just to inject whatever the helper needs to do its job.